# Allowing a class that inherits from an abstract class to return undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that looks like this:

```js
// step.ts

import { AllowedStepNames } from "./interfaces"; 

abstract class Step {
  abstract nextStep(): AllowedStepNames | undefined
}
```

Which in turn uses a type in a seperate file:

```js
// interfaces/index.ts

const stepList = {
  foo: "bar",
  bar: "baz"
};

export type AllowedStepNames = keyof typeof stepList;
```

I have a class that extends from it that looks like this:

```
// referral-reason.step.ts

export default class ReferralReasonStep extends Step {
  nextStep() {
    return this.params.reason === 'no-reason' ? 'foo' : undefined
  }
}
```

However, the compiler throws an error:

```
Property 'nextStep' in type 'NotEligibleStep' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Step'.
```

However, if I add the return type in my inherited class like so:

```
export default class ReferralReasonStep extends Step {
  nextStep(): AllowedStepNames | undefined {
    return this.params.reason === 'no-reason' ? 'foo' : undefined
  }
}
```

This seems strange to me, because I'd expect the extended class to inherit the return type from the abstract class. Can someone tell me what's going on? Or am I doing something wrong?

In addition, if I put all my classes and types in the same file, the problem goes away.

[Reproducable example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-meninsky-xrju0c?file=/src/not-eligible-step.ts)

Comment: in `AllowedStepNames` you have `'foo'|'bar'|'baz'` but you are returning `not-eligible` which is not in the union.

Comment: the second code block you posted does not work either because of the same problem

Comment: Whoops - bad copy paste error on my part!

Comment: Now there is [no error](https://tsplay.dev/WKq58N). Can you please create a reproducible example?

Comment: I've managed to reproduce it with [multiple files](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-meninsky-xrju0c?file=/src/not-eligible-step.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got the issue now:

TypeScript is automatically inferring the type `string` instead of `foo | undefined` to your function based on the return type and `string` is not assignable to the union `AllowedStepNames`.

What can you do to fix this?

#### Option 1

As you already said in the post, you can explicitly set the return type of the function to `foo | undefined`.

#### Option 2

The reason there was no error in the TypeScript playground is a difference in the tsconfig rules. I identified `strictNullChecks` to be the rule that changes this behavior. So depending on your project, you could enable this rule.

```
compilerOptions: {
  strictNullChecks: "true"
}
```

#### Option 3

By using `as const` you can tell the compiler to use the string literal value as the type instead of `string`.

```
nextStep() {
  return this.params.reason === "no-reason" ? "foo" as const : undefined;
}
```